# socket.io - Messages stored in db are being rendered twice

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building a chat rooms app in which i'm storing all messages in the database. When user joins same room again, app renders all previous messages from db. but I don't know why all those messages are being printed twice.

- on Server side

when user tries to join a room it checks if the room exist in db, if not it creates one. and if yes it sends the all the previous messages back to room

```js
     //Join -room

      socket.on('join-room', async (room) => {
          socket.join(room);

          let roomInDB = await Room.findOne({ name: room });
          if (roomInDB === null) {
              io.emit('err', { message: "Creating New Room!" })
              let newRoom = new Room({ name: room })
              await newRoom.save();
          } else {
              Room.findOne({ name: room }).populate('chats').exec((err, chats) => {
                  io.to(room).emit('room_data', chats);
              })
          }
     })
```

- On client side

I'm using a `displayMessage` function to render message in the room.

```js
function displayMessage(messageData, senderClass) {
    // message, sender, time

    const msg_box = document.getElementById("messages");
    const { sender, time, message } = messageData;
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add(senderClass, 'msg_card');

    if (senderClass === 'sent') {
        card.innerHTML = `
        <div class="msg_text">
         ${message}
        </div>
        <div class="time">${time}</div>
        `
    } else {
        card.innerHTML = `
        <div class="msg_text">
        <span class="sent_by">${sender.username}</span> - ${message}
        </div>
        <div class="time">${time}</div>
        `
    }

    msg_box.appendChild(card);
}
```

So, when user joins a room socket io sends previous messages back, and using `displayMessage` function I'm rendering those messages in the room but for some reason it's happening twice.

[image]

**I've tried console loggin when rendering these messages, but it logs correct number of messages and not twice.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend that you isolate which side the bug is in by testing a call to the server while taking the client out of the picture. You can do this by using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), which now has [SocketIO support](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-socket-io/). If you emit the event that joins a user into a room to the server once and get duplicate messages back, then the issue is on the server side. Otherwise, perhaps you are calling the rendering twice on the client side.

Comment: thanks man, your bug solving approach actually worked! The problem was in the client side...